# Is there a way to use a console clear method in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console, jline3

I've been trying to build a console clear command into my final assignment for school.

Beforehand I was trying to use a TerminalClear command; but this does not work as IntelliJ uses a Console instead of Terminal when running my application.

When researching my issue, I came across this [Quora Post](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-clear-the-console-screen-in-Java-using-intellij-For-example-I-am-trying-to-make-it-look-like-how-it-happens-when-we-use-system-cls-in-C), and I saw Philip Gust's answer to it.

I downloaded JLine-console-3.23.0.jar and I have been trying to get this to work based on the limited documentation on its functionalities (that I could find).

```
import org.jline.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TerminalClear {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Terminal terminal = TerminalBuilder.builder().build();

        // Clear the terminal screen using JLine
        terminal.puts(InfoCmp.Capability.clear_screen);
        terminal.flush();

        // Display a message to indicate that the console has been cleared
        System.out.println("Terminal cleared!");
    }
}
```

However its stricken with "Cannot resolve method / symbol 'x' " errors.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Ensure that JLine-console-3.23.0.jar was added to the project / module libraries. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-project-library

Comment: I did this, restarted IntelliJ and it still shows me the errors... :(